# How can I update a dynamic amount of records in one SQL query?

Tags: sql

An update query like:

```
UPDATE test
SET x = (case when id = 1 then 99
              when id = 2 then 98
                end),
    y = (case when id = 1 then 42
              when id = 2 then 41
                end)
```

will update multiple records where the x and y attributes have different values for each record. But what if the number of records I need to update is dynamic? For simplicity, assume I  have an array of `id` values. I want to update all the records that have an `id` in that array, and in one query. How could you do that?

Comment: SQL does not have a data type called "array", so your question is quite unclear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff think of the length of the array as the number of records I want to update. This will go in a ruby class. If `a = [1,2,3]` then I have then `a.length` gives me 3. So I want to update records when the ids are 1, 2, and 3. But the x and y attributes for each of those records are different, hence the case.

Comment: Doing this in "one query" is unlikely to be "better" or "faster" or "easier to read" or "easier to understand" than alttag's answer.  I guess if you wanted this to be more set oriented instead of loop-like, you could consider having or building a table of id , newXvalue, newYvalue and then do your updates with joins to that table, and equally passing the dyanamic number of id's in as a table (not an array) that can be joined with the table I just described.

Comment: @avery_larry after some outside investigation, your comment seems to outline the best approach. My guess is that would run faster as opposed to looping over the same query.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're already going about this the hard way. Your code is best accomplished with multiple queries:

```sql
UPDATE test
SET x = 99, y=42
WHERE id=1;

UPDATE test
SET x = 98, y=41
WHERE id=2;
```

As for updating "all the records" (as you say), that's a harder question to answer, as it's not clear where the data are coming from. That sort of thing might be best handled with a scripting language. You may have other options. depending on which database platform you're using, but you didn't specify that either.

Comment: I know how to do it with multiple queries. I'm trying to optimize performance, hence "one query". The number of records can be different each time the class is called.

Comment: "One query" is not the same  as "optimizing performance". The thing you almost always want to optimize is (1) ease of development and (2) ease of reading the code, because someone (you?) will have to maintain it later.

Comment: @Roberto A quote from the book _Computer Programming as an Art_ by Donald Knuth: _premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming_